# Julia find the index of the maximum element in a list that satisfies another list condition

Tags: julia, max, argmax

I want to find the index of the maximum element in a list that satisfy certain conditions.

I have two lists `a = [13, 17, 11, 24, 30]` and `b = [10, 12, 13, 20, 28]`. I want to find the index `i` of the maximum element in `b` such that `a[i]-b[i]>0`. The answer here is `i=5`. Mathematically, I am looking for `argmax_{i in S} b` where `S = {i : a_i - b_i > 0}`.

My solution sorts the list and filters it. Is there a better approach?

```
filter(in(findall(>(0), a .- b)), sortperm(b, rev=true))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following shows a method without a loop. Using a loop should be the easiest go-to solution.
Additionally, benchmarking is demonstrated. Also, the `let` block shows how to avoid allocations from capturing variables in a closure.

```
julia> a = [13, 17, 11, 24, 30] ; b = [10, 12, 13, 20, 28];

julia> @btime let a = $a, b = $b 
       findmax(i->a[i]>b[i] ? b[i] : typemin(Int), eachindex(a))
       end
  5.714 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
(28, 5)
```

For completeness, a benchmark of a `loop` version:

```
julia> @btime begin 
       mi = 0 ; m = typemin(Int); for i in eachindex($a)
       if $a[i] > $b[i] && $b[i] > m
           m = $b[i]
           mi = i
       end
       end; (m, mi)
       end
  5.495 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
(28, 5)
```

Comment: Isn't it better to write the code as a function? Advocating for function use is one of the standard tasks one has to do when advising on Julia performance, while the above code seems to promote a style that typically leads to problems. It also mixes benchmarking code with core functionality in a confusing way.

Comment: @DNF Yep, it's better to have it in a function in used code. For demo purpose i've left it outside. Hopefully, the reader can extract the method from the example. If you think it is too hidden for future readers, I'll edit the answer.